# How to seal bath spout nipple?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, spout

Our bath spout wasn't producing any water, so I took it off to take a look. Turns out there was a lot of grit in the little mesh filter in it - totally blocked. I cleaned it out, and now we have water. That's great.

Less great is my total inability to put it back together again properly. Given the amount of caulk and crap behind the cover (now scraped off), and the other tiling, I'm sure it's bit of a botched job to start with. Just need to fix it up.

I have the piping in the wall, into which I **think** I push the adaptor, using the nipple to screw it in. That all pretty much works, then the face plate goes over it, and the spout goes onto the adaptor, using a little grub screw to sit in place.

However, whenever I try to screw in the nipple, I can't because it's recessed into the wall, behind the tile, and I have no idea how to actually screw it fully in.

What tool can I use? Can't use an internal/nipple wrench, because the adaptor is inside the nipple. Can't use a regular socket, none seem to fit around it properly.

Is there something specific to fit it?

Parts are shown in the pics here: https://imgur.com/a/05UoE

In short -

1. How do I screw in the nipple tightly?
2. Am I thinking about this correctly?

[image: Nipple - note flat sides]
[image: Nipple and adaptor tube]
[image: Hole]
[image: Parts]

Note, the chrome collar can screw to the nipple, but then it protrudes too much for the plate to sit flush on the wall, and it's too fat to go through the plate hole, so seems to just sit flush with it as a spacer.

Comment: Alex- how did you initially remove the stem from the wall? Also, the split nipple should be oriented on the stem such that the notches are facing out?

Comment: Yes, I noticed that - in actually trying to replace it, I've had it the other way around. Just put it together for a pic, and realised after I had it the wrong way around.

Comment: And, I was an idiot - took it apart so easily I can't remember how, and didn't document it.

Answer (score 1):

So the adapter ring (the split threaded nipple) slips over the stem (the piece with the rubber O-rings). The stem is pushed into the supply pipe (in the wall). To connect the stem to the supply pipe the split threaded nipple is tightened until the stem is snug (the flat spots on the split nipple are there for a wrench). Next try sliding the chrome eschuteon plate on the stem and bring it to the wall. You should be able to fit the spout on to the stem and secure it to the wall plate.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that's my thinking. Any idea what sort of wrench? It's too far back in the wall for anything but a socket type to work, and no normal sockets fit it.

Comment: This is the tool that will tighten the split nipple : http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0000CBJG8?keywords=Adjustable%20Sink%20Wrench&qid=1449455921&ref_=sr_1_3&sr=8-3

Comment: I'm not sure the nipple needs to be tightened completely down. In fact if it is threaded until it can't go any further it may hinder the flow of water due to the stem base possibly being pushed against the inside of the pipe wall.

Comment: @ojait - The OP says that the split nipple goes into the hole in the wall to below the wall surface. How in the world would you expect that god awful tool that you linked to on Amazon to fit down into the wall hole to tighten the split nipple?? If you are going to suggest a tool I think that a far better one is in order.

Comment: Thanks for your constructive and thoughtful criticism. If you know that the tool I suggested will not work for this task, please feel free to recommend the specific tool that would help the OP to accomplish the task. (BTW: I happen to know God highly recommends this item and doesn't think it is awful.)

Comment: Please provide a documented citation for God's recommendation.